# in shiny app, reactive output gives error when used to subset

Tags: r, shiny

Here's a simple reproducible example of my problem.

**setup**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

original.data <- tibble(
  year = seq(2000, 2020, 2),
  count = rnorm(11)
)
```

This app works, but it gives an error.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("year"),
    ),
    # Show the table
    mainPanel(
    tableOutput("subset")  
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$year <- renderUI({
    shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput(inputId = "year",
                                  label = "Year to map",
                                  choices = seq(2000, 2020, 2),
                                  selected = 2020)
  })
  
  output$subset <- renderTable({
    original.data[original.data$year == input$year,]
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It looks like this: [image]

But it gives this error:

> Warning: Error in : Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
> ℹ Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
> x Input has size 11 but subscript `original.data$year == input$year` has size 0.

The error only occurs with the reactive input. If I move `sliderTextInput` into the `ui`, the app runs without an error.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput(inputId = "year",
                                    label = "Year to map",
                                    choices = seq(2000, 2020, 2),
                                    selected = 2020),
    ),
    # Show the table
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("subset")  
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$subset <- renderTable({
    original.data[original.data$year == input$year,]
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My actual use-case is a much more complicated application, where I need error-free reactive generated inputs. Does anyone see the error in my code?

Comment: The `size 0` can occur when the app is starting up, not all widgets have valid values when the first reactive component fires. For this reason, I suggest adding `req(input$year)` to the beginning of your `output$subset` block: it will prevent the block (and all chained-dependent reactive blocks) from firing until `input$year` is "truthy" (not null, has length, is not false, etc). See `?isTruthy` for some more on that.

Comment: For the `size 0` error, one can reproduce it with `original.data[original.data$year == NULL,]`, where the null is because `"year"` it not yet defined (or not yet non-null) in `input`. If you actually want a not-yet-defined year to result in 0 rows, then you can change it to `original.data[original.data$year %in% input$year,]`

Comment: really helpful! Thank you, @r2evans. If you leave this as an answer, I'll happily accept it. My actual use-case involved relying on this reactive output within an `observe` expression needed to create a leaflet map. Your solution solves the problem beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up front, add `req(input$year)` to your reactive block.

The `size 0` error can occur when the app is starting up: often with larger shiny apps (lots of components/widgets and reactive blocks) and with dynamic inputs, the input widget may not be completely defined when a reactive block fires. When that happens, `input$year` is not yet available, so it returns `NULL`. We can reproduce it with:

```r
tibble(mtcars)[mtcars$cyl == NULL,]
# Error: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
# i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
# x Input has size 32 but subscript `mtcars$cyl == NULL` has size 0.
```

Two ways to deal with this:

1. If you intend that the lack of `year` defined yet should mean the table is not rendered, then add `req(.)`, as in

   ```r
     output$subset <- renderTable({
       req(input$year)
       original.data[original.data$year == input$year,]
     })
   ```
2. If you think the table should be rendered but with 0 rows (similar but a little different), then you can use `%in%` instead of `==`:

   ```r
     output$subset <- renderTable({
       original.data[original.data$year %in% input$year,]
     })
   ```